# CAS: Invoking a webservice programmatically from within a servlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, cas

I have two applications running on 2 different servers (one on tomcat and other on JBoss). Both these applications are connected to the same CAS server for authentication. Right now this CAS server also resides within the same JBoss.

```
Say:
App-1 --- is on tomcat and CASified
App-2 --- is on JBoss and CASified
CAS   --- is on JBoss
```

Now that I am invoking an url of App-1 from a browser. The CAS login page comes up and after username/password is provided, the request now successfully enters the servlet of App-1. From this servlet code, I am trying to invoke a webservice that resides inside App-2.

```
Note: I use axis2 for this webservice and the axis2.war is also CASified
      to the same CAS server for authentication.
```

I could not make this webservice call work no matter what I do. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
Note: If I call the CAS REST api with a hardcoded username/password, I am 
getting the TGT, through which I am able to get the Service Ticket, with 
which I am able to invoke that web-service. But I do not want to login again 
with a hard-coded username or password. My webservice invocation should 
happen with the already logged-in user only.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the CAS Proxy feature.
The link 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough
helped a bit. But could not understand where to start with.
First take the CAS client jar from http://downloads.jasig.org/cas-clients/ . In my case I took `cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar` jar. I have included this jar in my application war.
In the web.xml of my application I have included the following 3 CAS Filters.

```
<!-- CAS Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>https://cas-hostname.domainname:port/cas</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://app-hostname.domainname:port</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>proxyCallbackUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://app-hostname.domainname:port/app/ticket</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>proxyReceptorUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>/app/ticket</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://cas-hostname.domainname:port/cas/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>https://app-hostname.domainname:port</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

  <!-- filter mappings -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ticket</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> Note-1: The order of filter mapping should be as mentioned above.
>   First CAS Validation filter mapping should come, followed by CAS
>   Authentication Filter and last the CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper
>   filter.
>
> Note-2: The URL pattern /ticket which is basically your proxy callback
>   url need not be mentioned in the last two filters.

Once CAS client jar is included in the web-app and web.xml configured with these filters, then all the http requests go through these filters.

So once your http requests entered your servlet, then you can call the following code snippet to get a proxy ticket:

```
String proxyTicket = ((AttributePrincipal) req.getUserPrincipal())
                .getProxyTicketFor(webservice_url);
```

`req` is the HttpServletRequest Object and `AttributePrincipal` is a class which is present in the `cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar`

This proxyTicket can then be appended to your web-service's URL as a query string like the following:

```
https://myother-webservice-app.com/ws/myData?ticket=<proxyTicket>
```

Once this URL is constructed, then you can make the web-service call programmatically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the web service on App-2 are you getting a session cookie back?  This should be the mechanism by which you're continuing to have access without reauthenticating on each call.  If you're not getting a cookie back, then there's no way in which to continue access without authenticating each time (i.e. there's no way for the server to remember that it's you and that it should trust the rest of the message).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The response to my web-service call is the CAS login page and I am stuck there.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood -- I had thought that the WebService was working when you called it with the Service Ticket in tow?  If so, I was wondering if the service was also returning a cooking in its response?  If not, a code snippet of the problem might help.

Comment: _CAS provides REST services to obtain TGT and subsequently service tickets from it. From inside the servlet, I programmatically invoke them to obtain the TGT(using a hardcoded username and password) and the service ticket. After it, I append the service ticket to the webservice url and invoke it successfully._ - This is what I was trying to explain in the last 'Note' in my question.

Comment: OK, good, I did understand then!  My question goes back, then, to /when the web service returns successfully/, is it (or the container) sending a session cookie back as part of the response?  Typically a CASified app would do so, resulting in a session cookie (JSESSIONID, etc.) which could be used as part of followon requests to access the service.

Comment: I am using axis2 client side APIs for making the webservice call. So I am not sure if it returns or not. It may return and I didn't dig into it much. But what I want is, that webservice call itself should be working with the current SSO session (which is the current servlet), without a new login to CAS.